# Matching substrings with PHP preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm attempting to create a lightweight BBCode parser without hardcoding regex matches for each element. My way is utilizing `preg_replace_callback()` to process the match in the function.

My simple yet frustrating way involves using regex to group the elements name and parse different with a switch for each function.

Here is my regex pattern:

```
'~\[([a-z]+)(?:=(.*))?(?: (.*))?\](.*)(?:\[/\1\])~siU'
```

And here is the `preg_replace_callback()` I've got to test.

```
return preg_replace_callback(
  '~\[([a-z]+)(?:=(.*))?(?: (.*))?\](.*)(?:\[/\1\])~siU', 
  function($matches) {
    var_dump($matches);
    return "<".$matches[1].">".$matches[4]."</".$matches[1].">";
  },
  $this->raw
);
```

This one issue has stumped me. The regex pattern won't seem to recursively match, meaning if it matches an element, it won't match elements inside it.

Take this BBCode for instance:

```
[i]This is all italics along with a [b]bold[/b].[/i]
```

This will only match the [u], and won't match any of the elements inside of it, so it looks like

> *This is all italics along with a [b]bold[/b].*

`preg_match_all()` continues to show this to be the case, and I've tried messing with greedy syntax and modes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Probably a duplicate. But 2 problems: 1. don't use the U modifier for performance and understanding reasons (instead choose soundly an appropriate character class with a greedy quantifier instead of the dot and avoid when possible non-greedy quantifiers), 2. It's impossible to do it in one pass: even if a pattern is able to match nested structures, you cannot use the match for the replacement. So the best strategy is to aim the innermost tags and to replace them in a loop until there is no more tags. Use the "count" parameter of `preg_replace_callback` to control the `do...while` loop.

Comment: Another idea: [`$str = preg_replace('~\[(\/?)([ib]\b)[^][]*\]~i','<$1$2>', $str);`](https://tio.run/##PYyxDoIwFEV3vuINJAVDbHQFZXVkcHt9mhYb@pLGNoXEjV@v4GByh3OGc6OLOXf9cBuKopyXBBcQyHR3PMM27T3woj2PO4f3BB9eHGhAQyb4F0pDR5RMov33MdnpmWz0erSVWBVWSvZ1hWxImRofhHRQtIpGdOWpPF9FA3tZbw92dOEnbc5f) if you already know about the taglist (add them to [the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/3ouwpX/1)). Of course this one does not check for pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Casimir et Hippolyte for their comment, I was able to solve this using a while loop and the count parameter like they said.

The basic regex strings don't work because I would like to use values in the tags like `[color=red]` or `[img width=""]`.

Here is the finalized code. It isn't perfect but it works.

```
$str = $this->raw;
do {
  $str = preg_replace_callback(
    '~\[([a-z]+)(?:=([^]\s]*))?(?: ([^[]*))?\](.*?)(?:\[/\1\])~si', 
    function($matches) {
      return "<".$matches[1].">".$matches[4]."</".$matches[1].">";
    },
    $str,
    -1,
    $count
  );
} while ($count);
return $str;
```

Comment: Ok. About the first point in my comment: instead of `(?:=(.*))?`, write something like `(?:=([^]\s]*))?` (instead of the dot, build a character class without the closing square bracket and without whitespace characters). Use the same idea to replace other dots in your pattern and to avoid non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: Also `while ($count)` suffices, since `$count` is evaluated to `false` when it is equal to 0.

Comment: About the point 2: the idea is to forbid other tags between the matched tags. So instead of `(.*?)` you can write something like `([^[]*)`.

Comment: I think I'm understanding now. Thanks. I'm still trying to get the hang of regex so this is much appreciated.